# Python + Testing + Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I am trying to mock an import during testing

Test.py looks like

```
# Store original __import__
orig_import = __import__

b_mock = mock.Mock()

def import_mock(name, *args):
    if name == 'B':
        return b_mock
   return orig_import(name, *args)

with mock.patch('__builtin__.__import__', side_effect=import_mock):
    import A
```

A.py looks like

```
import B

def a():
    return B.func()
```

Now

```
b_mock.func.return_value = 'spam'
```

Therefore, A.a() should return 'spam'
However, A.a() returns the entire mock object b_mock like this: < Mock name='mock.B.func()' id='139854736039632' >

Everytime B.func() is called, how do I get the return value which I have set(i.e 'spam') instead of getting the entire mock object?

Comment: I try it and works on my side. Can you cat and paste exactly the files `Test.py` and `A.py`? It seams to me you have something like `import bmodule as B` in `A.py`.